# Preserving date format in Google Sheets in nested IFS statement

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Sheet with nested `IF`s, so that I can display different concatenated results depending on a value that I type in a certain cell.

**Example:**

```
A1 - I can type "Dog" "Cat" or "Rabbit"
```

**Nested if** says:

```
If "Dog" is in A1, then in cell A2, return G2&D2&F2
```

It's more complex, but that's the idea. So, **formula** essentially looks like this:

```
=IFS($A$1="Dog",G2&D2&F2,$A$1="Cat",C2&F2,R2,$A$1="Rabbit",H2,M2,N2)
```

Assume in the above that F2 contains dates in the format `MM DD YY` (i.e. `12/01/20`).

- If I call for F2 alone, it preserves the date format.
- If I call F2 with other values (as above in the `Dog` and `Cat` examples), I get back a serial text string instead of the date-formatted value.

I want the date formatting of F2 to be preserved within `Dog` and `Cat`. How can I incorporate this into my `IF` statements and preserve the date formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Found a thread from which I was able to deduce the answer. Here is the correct solution:

Instead of merely retrieving &F2, I substituted the following:

&TEXT(F2,"DDD, m/dd")

**DDD, m/dd** was the format I chose for the particular results I was seeking.

This returns "Mon, 8/3" for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Just note that Text changes the "date" from a true date to text that looks like a date.  It may be better to format the cell itself as `DDD, m/dd`